# Can limits be simplified by substituting asymptotic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

For example, The limit
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(x+\sin(x)+\cos(x))^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
as $x$ goes to $0$, $\sin(x)\sim x$ and $\cos(x)\sim 1$.
In what conditions can I substitute the asymptotic functions into the limit respectively?
In this case it would be
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(2x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e^2$$
which is the correct answer. I've tried a few different limits as well and I can't find a counterexample, so I wonder

$(1)$ is this technique of substituting the function valid?

$(2)$ If not, in what condition does this work?

Attempt proof:
let $f_1,f_2,...,f_m$ be the original function and let ,$g(f_1,f_2,...,f_m)$ be a function that groups them together (In my example $g(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)=(f_1+f_2+f_3)^{f_4}$). for example in my limit $f_1(x)=x$, $f_2(x)=\sin(x)$ etc.
and let $\alpha_{i}\sim f_i$ be asymptotic functions of $f_i$ as $x$ goes to $a$. So in my example $\alpha_2(x)=x$. I want to show that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(f_1,f_2,....,f_m)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_{m})$$

$\mathbf{Proof}$
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(f_1,f_2,....,f_m)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g\left(\frac{f_1}{\alpha_1}\alpha_1,\frac{f_2}{\alpha_2}\alpha_2,....,\frac{f_m}{\alpha_m}\alpha_m\right)$$
$\color{green}{\mathrm{Assuming}}$ $g$ is continuous and all $f_1,...,f_m$ are continuous
$$\color{red}{=}\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f_1}{\alpha_1}\alpha_1,\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f_2}{\alpha_2}\alpha_2,....,\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f_m}{\alpha_m}\alpha_m\right)$$ for some limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\alpha_k$ doesn't exist like $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}$ like in my example just don't switch the limit into $g$
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\alpha_1,\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\alpha_2,...,\alpha_k,...,\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\alpha_m\right)$$
$$\color{red}{=}\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,....,\alpha_m)$$
The steps where it might need justification has written in red on the equality sign. So my question is

$(3)$ With the $\color{green}{\mathrm{Assumption}}$ is the proof correct?

$(4)$ if not, point out the wrong steps.

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than trying to figure out a set of conditions to allow replacements like those it is much simpler to use limit laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) No. Example $e^x\sim_{x\to0}1$ but $\lim_{x\to0}(e^x)^{1/x}=e\ne\lim_{x\to0}1^{1/x}=1.$

(2) It works inside products (it is designed for it), i.e. if $f_i\sim_ag_i$ then $f_1f_2\sim_ag_1g_2$, hence also in well-defined quotients.

(3) No. See (4).

(4) The RHS of your 1st red = (hence that = and everything after it) makes little sense because the argument of $g$ in it are constants, not depending on any $x$ tending to $a.$

Comment: (1) Thanks, for the example. I guess the asymptotic behavior is not sufficient, probably have to use stuff like Taylor series

(4)I don't understand? $\alpha_i$ are functions of $x$ , not constants.

Comment: After your *first* red =, the arguments of $g$ are limits, hence constants.

Comment: I guess I should've typed it like this $\left[\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f_i/\alpha_i\right]\alpha_i$

Comment: But then this = (with your convention of "not switching" $1/x$) would be false: again, $\lim_{x\to0}(e^x)^{1/x}\ne\lim_{x\to0}([\lim_{x\to0}e^x/1]1)^{1/x}.$

Comment: I understand I am wrong, Anyways thanks for your answer. I think the asymptotic functions have to be carefully chosen. In your example, if you replace $1$ with $1+x$ the thing works

Comment: It works because $1+x$ is the (polynomial part of the) Taylor developement of $e^x$ at the order $1,$ not simply because $e^x\sim_01+x$ ($e^x\sim_01+2x$ as well). The method is not to "choose carefully asymptotic functions". It is to give up the notion of asymptotic functions and use a finer notion.